# Check validity of an OracleDependency

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I am continuously running a service (coded in c#) on a Windows server, and I am using the OracleDependency object (provided by ODP.NET) to monitor changes affecting some tables in an Oracle (11g) database.

I'm using the OracleDependency as a permanent listener (infinite timeout), and so far I did not experience any problem. I am wondering, however, which is the best way to check that my OracleDependency listener is still valid?

Answer (score -1):

Make a change to the table and see if the event fires.